# Excel power query connect to Oracle error: Oracle: ORA-06401: NETCMN: invalid driver designator

Tags: excel, oracle11g, powerquery

I'm trying to get an Oracle DB with excel power query and I'm getting this error:
Oracle: ORA-06401: NETCMN: invalid driver designator

Excel and power query are 32 bits.
The oracle instant client is installed and I tried both 32 and 64 bits versions.
The oracle DB is 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit.
I can connect with sqlplus without a problem.

The only references I can find to the problem are references to wrong characters in the tsnames.ora file, but I'm not using it, as I'm using the connection with all the info like server:1521/service_name

Not sure what excel is really using to connect, but from the docs it should be using instant client. And it's working because I tested it through ODBC, which works fine with the driver.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is... If you click Send-A-Frown you can get in contact with one our support and they have a lot of experience fixing driver problems!

Comment: thanks @CarlWalsh, will do.

Comment: I would normally install the Oracle full client, not the instant client.

Comment: Got that one installed, sqlplus connects without a problem.